# Get huge amount of characters from text file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an excel vba where you can select 50,000 characters from a text file containing 30,000,000 characters. In fact, my file is a DNA sequence of an entire chromosom (Fasta) and I need to copy multiple sequence of 50,000 characters from that file and paste it in a cell. I have to do that for 10 different text files. I don't know the characters, I only knows the position of those characters.

```
'Get i to character 22,000,000
For i = 22,000,000 to 22,050,000
'Copy those characters to range A1
Next
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your code attempt? Also, you have not ask a question yet (only stated your requirements).

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're having with implementing this?  There are plenty of resources to be had via googling "VBA read text file" (for example) which should get you started.  If you run into problems with your code then you can post here with a description of the exact issue(s) you're having with it.

Comment: Excel cannot store 50,000 characters in one cell. The maximum is 32,767 characters. See this [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013)

Comment: A little bit more context might help you get useful suggestions.  Why do you need these parts of the file?  What are you going to do with the sequences after you've extracted them?  You can't put them into singe cells, so would splitting them across cells work?  You could also consider extracting them to another file for example.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer, in fact those characters are DNA sequence and I'd like to compare them but with a limit under 50,000 characters i think i'll go with extraction to another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DNA sequence of more then 30 millions characters seems to be too heavy for excel vba and an extraction of 50,000 characters into a cell is impossible. I'll have to extract the sequence directly to an other text file. Thanks for all your answers.